# What is the name of feature that allows separate function implementations for different values of parameters?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, language-features

In some programming languages one can specify the function implementation for particular values of arguments:

```
factorial[x] = x * factorial[x-1]
factorial[0] = 1
```

Calling the function with `0` will use the second definition while calling it with `3` will use the first definition.

I am aware that this is a kind of function overloading, but if I would search for languages with function overloading, I will find a lot that don't have this feature but only overload depending on arity or types. Is there a more specific name for this?

Comment: C++ templates have this concept for types. One can supply different implementations of the template for specific types. These implementations are called _specializations_. See [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such [case-by-case functions](https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/FieldGuide/piecewise/lesson.html) are known as [piecewise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) in mathematics. For example, in Scala they can be implemented using `case` statements like so

```
val factorial: Int => Int = {
  case 0 => 1
  case x => x * factorial(x - 1)
}
```

which outputs

```
factorial(4) // res1: Int = 24
```

This is a form of function definition using [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html).

Similarly, in Haskell we can define a function using pattern matching like so

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer 
factorial 0 = 1
factorial x = x * factorial (x - 1)
```